# Issues parsing string

Tags: c++, string, find

I am trying to enter a new line every time my count comes to 4 OR if I come across this character ']'.

Right now, I can get my code to create a new line every time my count is 4, but when I add the condition for the ']' I get a new line on every iteration.  I think this might be caused by my chartDataString.find(']') but I'm not sure how to fix it.

can you see the issue with this code?:

```
int barCount = 0;
size_t start = 0;
size_t n = 0;
int charCount = 0;
while ((start = chartDataString.find(" |", start)) != string::npos) {
    ++barCount;
    start+=2;
    charCount++;
    if (barCount == 4  || chartDataString.find("]")) {
        //cout<<"Number of bars: "<<barCount<<endl;
        chartDataString.insert(start, "\n");
        barCount = 0;
        charCount= 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (barCount == 4  || chartDataString.find("]"))
```

If `string.find()` returns `string::npos`, then the above statement will evaluate to `true`, because `string::npos` is most likely NOT 0.

On my machine it is 18446744073709551615, which the program casts to `true`

As Anish Ram pointed out in the comments, `string::npos` [is defined as](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/):

```
   static const size_t npos = -1;
```

So, as a `size_t`, it will always be a positive value, which when casted to a boolean, will evaluate as true.

try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  if (string::npos) cout << "Entered if statement" << endl;
  else cout << "DID NOT ENTER IF STATEMENT" << endl;

}
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 and the output of the program is:

> Entered if statement

Change your code to read:

```
if (barCount == 4  || chartDataString.find("]") != string::npos)
```

And things should work just fine. Well they should at least compile....
If what you're trying to do is iterate over all the characters in the string, then you should really be checking each position in the string instead of calling `string::find()`

In that case, you should instead maintain an index into the string and then check `string.at(index) == ']';` instead.

Comment: `std::string::npos` [seems to be defined as -1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)

Comment: Yeah I never said what you posted is wrong. Just that that is the definition :)

Comment: @AnishRam: Notice that it is a `size_t` that is being defined as -1, not an int. `size_t` will always be positive

Comment: Your result is correct. `npos` seems to have an unsigned type. So -1 would be = 18446744073709551615 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the `chartDataString` contains a `]` at all with `chartDataString.find("]")`.  Also `find` will return the position the character is found, or `string::npos` if it is not found.  The only time `find` will evaluate to false is when the character is found in the first character.

Instead, try:

```
if(barCount == 4  || chartDataString.at(charCount) == ']') {
```

This checks if the current character is a `]`.  Note, it's not clear to me what your current character position is.  You may need to replace `charCount` with `start`.

Comment: I think the actual position to search at may be `start`, not `charCount`, judging by the other logic.  Other than that, I believe you've got the right idea here.